# Performance test using elapsed milliseconds in API GetSystemTime

Tags: excel, vba

**Task**

I'm doing some performance tests measuring the elapsed time between start time (st1) and end time (st1).
As I want to show also milliseconds I'm using the API function GetSystemTime:

```
GetSystemTime st1   ' get start time as system time
GetSystemTime st2   ' get end   time as system time
```

**Problem**

It is not possible to simply substract

```
st2 - st1
```

, because this results in an Error 13 message. So far I didn't find any solutions, but succeeded in creating a simple work around function SystemTimeDiff(st1 As SYSTEMTIME, st2 As SYSTEMTIME).

**Question**

I would like to know if there exists an easier approach or a SystemTimeDiff function - comparable for example to DateDiff?

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

' API Declaration
Private Declare Sub GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32" ( _
        lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)

Private Type SYSTEMTIME
  wYear As Integer
  wMonth As Integer
  wDayOfWeek As Integer
  wDay As Integer
  wHour As Integer
  wMinute As Integer
  wSecond As Integer
  wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

' ================
' Performance Test
' ================
Sub TestSystemTimeDifference()
  Dim st1       As SYSTEMTIME
  Dim st2       As SYSTEMTIME
  GetSystemTime st1     ' Start time

  ' Do something
  ' ............

  GetSystemTime st2     ' End time

' ================
  ' Show System time elapsed with milliseconds as work around
' ================
  MsgBox SystemTimeDiff(st1, st2), vbInformation, "Systemtime elapsed"

End Sub


' ==============
' My Work around
' ==============
Function SystemTimeDiff(st1 As SYSTEMTIME, st2 As SYSTEMTIME)
  Dim msec1     As Integer: Dim msec2 As Integer
  Dim timetaken As Date
  msec1 = Val(Left(Split(FormatSystemTime(st1) & ".", ".")(1) & "000", 3))
  msec2 = Val(Left(Split(FormatSystemTime(st2) & ".", ".")(1) & "000", 3))
  If msec2 < msec1 Then msec2 = msec2 + 1000
  timetaken = CDate(Split(FormatSystemTime(st2) & ".", ".")(0)) - CDate(Split(FormatSystemTime(st1), ".")(0))
  SystemTimeDiff = FormatSystemTime(st1) & vbNewLine & FormatSystemTime(st2) & vbNewLine & _
              (Format(Hour(timetaken), "00") & ":" & Format(Minute(timetaken), "00") & ":" & Format(Second(timetaken), "00")) & _
              "." & Format(msec2 - msec1, "000")

End Function

Function FormatSystemTime(st As SYSTEMTIME) As String
' Purpose: returns formatted system time with milliseconds
' cf Site: http://www.vbarchiv.net/tipps/tipp_1493-timestamp-inkl-millisekunden.html
  With st
    FormatSystemTime = Format(.wHour, "00") & ":" & Format(.wMinute, "00") & ":" & _
    Format(.wSecond, "00") & "." & Format(.wMilliseconds, "000")
  End With
End Function
```

Comment: Why not just use `Timer`? It's resolution about 15 msec. To make measurements more accurate you may repeat a sample e. g. 10 times within a loop, and divide total time by 10, then you get resolution 1.5 msec.

Comment: retrieve milliseconds  ... `ms = st1.wMilliseconds`  .... as per @omegastripes, Timer is a better option. windows does NOT resolve time down to a millisecond anyway (afaik)

Comment: @jsotola, thanks for helpful comments, though not an answer to my question, which remains unresolved :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this

```
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Sub timeMe()

    Dim start As Long, fini As Long
    Dim total As Long
    Dim ms As Long, sec As Long, min As Long, hr As Integer

    start = GetTickCount()

    Dim i, j: For i = 0 To 1000000: j = i ^ 2: Next i

    fini = GetTickCount()

    total = fini - start

'   total = 7545023                 ' test value:    2:05:45.023
'   total = 460382417               ' test value:  127:53:02.417

    ms = total Mod 1000
    sec = total \ 1000
    min = sec \ 60
    hr = min \ 60

    sec = sec Mod 60
    min = min Mod 60


    Debug.Print "runtime "; hr & ":" & Format(min, "00") & ":" & Format(sec, "00") & "." & Format(ms, "000")

End Sub
```

Comment: i like your code because it shows total milliseconds as well as a formatted result (hh:mm:ss.000).

Comment: though all comments (integrated Timer measuring in centiseconds) as well as both answers offer a valid statement, you were the first to come nearest to my question getting it simple.

Answer (score 1):

The [TimeGetTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629(v=vs.85).aspx) function returns the number of milliseconds since the system was started, and is fairly easy to use.

```
Private Declare Function timeGetTime Lib "winmm.dll" () As Long

public Sub test()
Dim started As Long
Dim ended   As Long   

started = timeGetTime ' Get milliseconds since startup
'//Do your work that you want timed here    
ended = timeGetTime
Debug.Print "Time Taken = " & ended - started  & " milliseconds"
End Sub
```

You can of course, divide the difference to turn milliseconds into seconds, minutes, and hours.  Watch for the fact that a Long data type has limited length, and if the elapsed time goes over around 25 days will set it to be a negative number (the VBA Long data type has a maximum of 2,147,483,647, which is around 24.85 days)

Comment: this is a valuable alternative and a helpful remark.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

' System MS Excel version 2010, VBA7 and Windows 10_64bit
' API Declaration
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)

Private Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear         As Integer
    wMonth        As Integer
    wDayOfWeek    As Integer
    wDay          As Integer
    wHour         As Integer
    wMinute       As Integer
    wSecond       As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type
```

```
' ================
' Performance Test
' ================
Sub TestSystemTimeDifference()
    Dim st1       As SYSTEMTIME
    Dim st2       As SYSTEMTIME
    Dim st3       As SYSTEMTIME

    Dim Stamp1mS  As Integer
    Dim Stamp2mS  As Integer
    Dim Stamp3mS  As Integer
    Dim Stamp1sec As Integer
    Dim Stamp2sec As Integer
    Dim Stamp3sec As Integer

    GetSystemTime st1     ' Start time
    Sleep 1               ' Do something
    GetSystemTime st2     ' Another moment
    Sleep 3               ' Do something else
    GetSystemTime st3     ' End time

    ' ================
    ' Show System time elapsed with milliseconds as work around
    ' ================
    ' MsgBox SystemTimeDiff(st1, st2), vbInformation, "Systemtime elapsed" ;
    ' be aware Stamp2mS might be less than Stamp1mS
    Stamp1mS = st1.wMilliseconds
    Stamp2mS = st2.wMilliseconds
    Stamp3mS = st3.wMilliseconds
    Stamp1sec = st1.wSecond
    Stamp2sec = st2.wSecond
    Stamp3sec = st3.wSecond
    MsgBox ("You can use the result for futher calculations." + Chr(13) + Chr(13) + Str(Stamp1sec) + "  " + Str(Stamp1mS) + Chr(13) + Str(Stamp2sec) + "  " + Str(Stamp2mS) + Chr(13) + Str(Stamp3sec) + "  " + Str(Stamp3mS))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code. However, it would be nice for future visitors of this question if you'd explain in your own words what the problem is, and how you think you solved it. Currently, this is not an answer but just a bunch of code.

Comment: Side note as friendly hint: think you need a further API declaration for VBA7 to run *Sleep*: `Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)`